# Change schedule task through cmd

Tags: cmd, scheduled-tasks

I want to change my task schedule time via a cmd command. I have already created it but I want to remove the double quote (`"`) from the arguments.

For example in the property-arguments of my previous schedule tak created .. ("http://mysite/script") I want to remove the double quote (`"`) and insert the single quote (`'`).

How can I do this through a cmd command?

I am getting error and I cannot remove the double quote from the `http://` link.

I did that with PowerShell `4.0`:

```powershell
$mycommand = ' /C  schtasks /change /TN "MyScheduletask" /TR ('http://mywebsite.com/myscript.ps1')'
start-process  cmd $mycommand;
```

All the time I have double quote (`"`) inside the link and not single quote(`'`)

Comment: `cmd` doesn't work with single quotes. Unlike Powershell, `cmd` arguments have to be enclosed in double quotes. As long as you pass anything to `cmd`, use double quotes.

Comment: i have just used your tips but at the end the results are the same in task schedule.